# In Angular, with a portal opened in another window, how do I attach an overlayRef so it will use the component's styles?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

In angular you have the CDK Portal library. From other sources on the internet I saw someone take a portal and open it in another window.  It works.  Then I wanted to see if I can make a dialog open in front of a portal window.  This kind of works, because indeed the component is showing in the portal window, which is what I want, but the styles are not showing up, because I have a problem in attaching the overlay.

All I want to do, is open a dialog in front of a portal window (it would if it would just honor my styles in the login.component.scss).  Now I KNOW you can use global styles. I could put the styles in the styles.css file, but I absolutely need to avoid doing this because of something I need to do later.

It's allot of code, so I included a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-1ekpdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwindow.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog-tokens.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog-ref.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).  The problem is attaching overlays somewhere.

Here is the problem code in the dialog service

```
open<T>(...){
  ...
  // Attach component portal to the overlay
  const comp = new ComponentPortal(component, null, injector);

  //This attaches the overlay to the main component (in our case app.component), 
  //but I don't want that, I want to attach to the window portal
  overlayRef.attach(comp);

  //THIS attaches to the portal, but doesn't use my styles in the login.component.scss
  portalWindow.externalPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal(comp);

  ...
}
```

Again, I KNOW I can put styles in the styles.css file and it will "work", but that will give me problems later on down the road, so I must avoid that.

Ideas were pulled from [John Woodruff website](https://johnbwoodruff.com/posts/angular-cdk-dialog/) where I got I use his open method and dialog service since it ties well with my question

I also got this rudimentary portal window from [rohyadev stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-portal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The basic module styles I simply got from W3Schools website.  I simply slapped all of this together in order to ask my question.

Comment: I'm beginning to think, what I'm asking for is simply not possible, and if that is the case, let me know (been on this problem for three days)

Comment: Very cool concept and implementation, but for every use case i think, a better solution with routing comes to mind, what did they use this method for?

Comment: @Skin_phil, At the company I work for, my product owner wanted to incorporate a portal window for a couple areas in the code I'm working on.  Mat dialogs as you know are anchored to the screen they are on, whereas a window can be moved anywhere.

As a side note, the above code of course is publicly founded code I got from the internet, as the portal window I'm working on is much more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I need to tell the portal window to append the styles of the new component we want in the portal window.  So the problametic code is solved by doing this instead

```
open<T>{
  ...
  // Attach component portal to the overlay
  const comp = new ComponentPortal(component, null, injector);

  portalWindow.externalPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal(comp);

  //This is the answer to the problem, manually attach the styles
  //to the portal window
  portalWindow.appendStyles();
  ...
}
```

So inside the portal window component we add that method like this

```
public appendStyles(){
  document.querySelectorAll('link, style').forEach(htmlElement => {
     this.externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(htmlElement.cloneNode(true));
  });
}
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-1ekpdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwindow.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog-tokens.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog-ref.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts,src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: Barring a more sophisticated and better solution, I will accept my answer if no other alternatives are better.